# Make navigation bar on the top right

Tags: html, css, navigation, margin, padding

I want to create navigation bar contains logo (left) and the list (right)
here is my code
[image]

```
     <nav>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="logo">SPIRIT8</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
       </nav>
```

I want li tags move to the right all the way. I can not make it by margin-right:0 li (the yellow box), or padding-right:0 ul (the red box)
I use grid bootstrap but don't know why ul  (the red border) have space on the right eventhough I set width 100%.

This is the result that I want : http://themeforces.com/demo/freebies/tf-free-no.3/

my css :

```
 nav {
   height: 70px;
   line-height: 70px;
   border: 1px  solid green;
 }

 nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 60%;
  margin-right: 0;
  border : 1px solid yellow;
 }
```

Comment: The example u shared ,they are using bootstrap navbar..You can use too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see here with bootstrap included

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/9m1jfjbs/)**

code :

```
 nav ul {
     list-style: none;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid red;
     text-align: right;
  }
```

`padding-right:0` and `margin-right:0` have no effect in your problem because the ul is already as aligned right as it can be ( it has no margin and no padding ) .

if you have smth like **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/9m1jfjbs/1/)**

```
.nav ul {
padding-right:20px;
margin-right:100px;
text-align:right;
}
```

then yes. adding `margin-right:0` and `padding-right:0` would have helped.
but in your case...the margin and padding are already at `0`

plus...you do not use margin or padding to align left or right. you either use `floats` or `text-align`

Answer (score 1):

You can add navbar ul text-align:right;

```
 nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: right;
 }
```

Here is **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swaranan/sfzzaosf/)**

Comment: it works, ty very much, idk why did not think about that, can anyone tell me why ul : padding-right:0; or li : margin-right:0 does not work? I''m just trying to understand the basic

Comment: You can use also bootstrap navbar...https://jsfiddle.net/swaranan/zw9420dc/

Comment: I just see it, it looks easy to use but I dont know how to style it yet, thank you for recommendation